# How to make PowerShell wait till output of the command is shown?

Tags: powershell, cmd

How to make powershell show output of the second command before executing the third command?

`Write-Host 'List of disks:'`
`Get-PhysicalDisk`
`$number = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please choose number from disks above:'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly piping your output to an `Out-*` or `Format-*` command usually causes PowerShell to finish outputting synchronously:

```
Write-Host 'List of disks:'
Get-PhysicalDisk |Out-Default # or `...|Format-Table`
$number = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please choose number from disks above:'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **pause** command within a computer batch file. It allows the computer to pause the currently running batch file until the user presses any key.

so, after the second command use **pause** in the next line and then enter third command in the script.